# Why is peanut butter viscous?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, food-chemistry, fats

Why is it that when you chop peanuts, a highly viscous paste is created?

Im assuming that the reason that chopped peanuts dont become just dust is because we cannot chop finely enough, but what causes the chopped particles to adhere to each other?

Comment: Well, that's mostly fat, so...

Comment: To expand on @Mithoron's comment - the peanut is not a homogeneous substance. Instead, it is comprised of many compounds. Therefore, it can not be neatly subdivided to infinity. The peanut oils behave such that they will come out and make the slurry that we call peanut butter.

Answer (score 1):

Peanuts contain peanut oil. When you crush the peanut you also compress some of the peanut oil out out of the nut particles.

Comment: Ok so you now have some oil/solid mixture, so what?

Comment: Do the experiment. Try mixing some vegetable oil with flour. The flour doesn't dissolve, you just get a paste.